# stripping newlines with islower function

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a text where there are two newlines in the middle of a sentence.

I thought that this could be a solution:

If the line starts with a lowercase letter and the previous line is empty, then strip the two \n\n that precede it

```
with open ("file.txt") as infile:   
prevLine = ""

    for line in infile:
        if line[0].islower()and not prevLine:
            print (line.strip())
        else:
            print(line)
    prevLine=line
```

But it doesn´t work (I´ve also tried with lstrip).What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

*I have a text where there are two newlines in the middle of a sentence.*   strip will only strip leading or trailing elements so you need `str.replace`:

```
line.replace("\n\n"," ") 

In [41]: line = "foo\n\nbar"

In [42]: line
Out[42]: 'foo\n\nbar'

In [43]: line.strip()
Out[43]: 'foo\n\nbar'

In [44]: line.replace("\n\n"," ")
Out[44]: 'foo bar'
```

If you don't want to add a space you can  also  use str.translate:

```
In [50]: line = "foo\n\nbar"

In [51]:  line.translate(None,"\n\n")
Out[51]: 'foobar'
```

There is some ambiguity in your questions as you also mention newlines preceding the line which would then mean be a `"\n"` which is not lowercase so you would need something like `if line.startswith("\n\n")`.

If by preceding you mean the previous line then you are trying to strip from the wrong line and your `not prevLine` will be False .

```
In [54]: "\n\n".islower()
Out[54]: False

In [55]: bool("\n\n")
Out[55]: True
In [56]: not bool("\n\n")
 Out[56]: False
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have read the line you are examining, the line you needed to strip newlines from was the preceding line.  Maybe try printing without newlines, then add them back if the line does not start with a lowercase letter.

```
newlines = ''
with open("file.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if newlines != '' and not line[0].islower():
            print newlines,
        stripped = line.rstrip('\n')
        newlines = line[len(stripped):]
        #print '#newlines=%r' % newlines
        print stripped,
if newlines:
    print newlines,
```

(Assuming Python2.x; adjust for Python3.x.)

Answer (score -1):

Your code doesn't work because you iterate your text by lines, so in case of \n\n you have just an empty line. If your text file isn't very big you can try something like this:

```
import re

with open("file.txt") as infile:
    buf = infile.read()
    print re.sub(r"\n\n", ' ', buf)
```